# Identifying the source for a dynamic text variable

Tags: flash-cs3

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm a newbie working to modify a flash template, so... Sorry.

I have a dynamic text field on the stage. It's assigned a variable name of "a3". When the flash runs, it loads that text field with the value of a text field in an html file called "text.html", in which the corresponding variable name is &prices_txt3. WHERE is the connection between the field name in the html file (&prices_txt3) and the field name for the dynamic text variable (a3) made? The "a3" variable is being used to populate the same text into two different dynamic text fields and I need to put different text into the second field. Just can't figure out how to get it done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need ActionScript editor tab

watch it here

http://tv.adobe.com/#vi+f15914v1003

and after this just look up for your variable name in code.

try to modes:
click on stage and review the as3 tab
and click on your element and review as3 tab

Answer (score 0):

Do you see "ExternalInterface" anywhere in your actionscript code?

Comment: @Greg: just review your all js/html files for that word, if so - you'll find a solution there, if no - try to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517906/identifying-the-source-for-a-dynamic-text-variable/3517948#3517948